# Using Arcpy to create tool to buffer 2 feature classes

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, arctoolbox, python-toolbox

I am trying to create a toolbox that will generate a buffer around 2 feature classes. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwLZL.png)

I feel like I am missing out a few minor things and that there is something wrong with my toolbox parameters?

Comment: please add you code as text, rather than an image

Comment: @MacroZED done it

Comment: Buffer roads, buffer schools, erase road buffer with school buffer using Erase tool

Comment: @BERA I think i have an issue with the buffer aspect of my code. When I specify the buffer distances for the 2 feature classes in the tool - the result shows both feature classes having the same buffer distance

Comment: @BERA Yes that what it is - 1000 meters

Comment: yup - within my parameters it has been listed as a linear unit  - so the user selects from the list of units available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
for fc in bufferList:
     arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2), "", "", "ALL")
     arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3), "", "", "ALL")
```

You are buffering roads twice, first with 1000 m and then you overwrite this with a buffer of 100 m, then you are doing the same for the schools.

There is no need to use a for loop. And Erase tool is what you want:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '_buffer', arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2), "", "", "ALL")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '_buffer', arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3), "", "", "ALL")

arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '_buffer', erase_features=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '_buffer', out_feature_class=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
```